# Magento : Validation Onblur

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, validation, form-validation

I want to validate my form, by events onblur for every input.

```
function validate_field(id){
  Validation.validate(id);
}
```

not work for me

I want to validation every single element. How to make this?

Comment: This is your custom form? Can you describe about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set property

```
Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;
```

This will cause validation to occur if an elements value has been changed and it looses focus.

Place this code before your form object gets initialised by enclosing it in script tags like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;
<script>
```